# perl script to create xml from mysql query - out of memory

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

I need to generate an XML file from database records, and I get the error "out of memory". Here's the script I am using, it's found on Google, but it's not suitable for me, and it's also killing the server's allocated memory. It's a start though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:db_name;host=host_address','db_user','db_pass')
  or die DBI->errstr;

# Get an array of hashes
my $recs = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('SELECT * FROM my_table',{ Columns => {} });

# Convert to XML where each hash element becomes an XML element
my $xml = XMLout( {record => $recs}, NoAttr => 1 );

print $xml;

$dbh->disconnect;
```

This script only prints the records, because I tested with a where clause for a single row id.

- First of all, I couldn't manage to make it to save the output to a file.xml.
- Second, I need somehow to split the "job" in multiple jobs and then put together the XML file all in one piece.

I have no idea how to achieve both.

**Constraint:** No access to change server settings.

Comment: hi, it does not seems to be bash, but a perl scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are problem lines:

```
my $recs = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('SELECT * FROM my_table',{ Columns => {} });
```

This reads the whole table into memory, representing every single row as an array of values.

```
my $xml = XMLout( {record => $recs}, NoAttr => 1 );
```

This is probably even larger structure, it is a the whole XML string in one go.

The lowest memory-use solution needs to involve loading the table one item at a time, and printing that item out immediately. In DBI, it is possible to make a query so that you fetch one row at a time in a loop.

You will need to play with this before the result looks like your intended output (I haven't tried to match your `XML::Simple` output - I'm leaving that to you:

```
print "<records>\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table');
$sth->execute;

while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
  # Convert db row to XML row
  print XMLout( {row => $row}, NoAttr => 1 ),"\n";
}

print "</records>\n";
```

Perl can use e.g. `open( FILEHANDLE, mode, filename )` to start access to a file and `print FILEHANDLE $string` to print to it, or you could just call your script and pipe it to a file e.g. `perl myscript.pl > table.xml`

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! it woks but it pull out all the details from db... i need to get only a few, (id, name, user, email, phone, date). This will do the job,    "SELECT id, name, user, email, phone, date FROM my_table" but now it comes to the xml format with must be like this     <user_ids>
    <user_id>2323</user_id><user_first_name>john</user_first_name>
    <user_id>123</user_id><user_email>email@domain.com</user_email>    <user_phone>123-123-1234</user_hone><user_date>2013-01-01</user_date></user_ids>
And i didn't manage to output the rows to an xml file...

Comment: If you want specific XML elements, you will need to name them in Perl so that XML::Simple knows what to do with them. You can do this by creating a Perl hash from your array. If the first db columns are `id` and `name` then you could start with `my $hashed_row = { user_id => $row->[0], user_first_name => $row->[1] }` - I think from that you can work out how to make the rest. You may still have more to do, but I think that should get you close

Answer (score 0):

It's the select * with no contraints that will be killing your memory. Add some constraint to your query ie date or id and use a loop to execute the query and do your output in chunks. That way you won't need to load the whole table in mem before your get started on the output.